# How do I make work Redux Theme Options Panel Work?

Tags: wordpress, redux-framework

My theme is using redux framework. Not as a plugin it is inside the theme. If I change anything from theme options panel nothing happens. It seems changed in theme options panel but it doesnt effect the frontend. In theme options page there is some error.

> Did you know that Redux sets a global variable for you? To access
>   any of your saved options from within your code you can use your
>   global variable: $emallshop_options

this variable is changing for whatever write in theme_options.php in

> 'global_variable'      => '',

if I write something in global variable the text turns to this variable. Like I wrote stackover in to global variable it's turn to

> Did you know that Redux sets a global variable for you? To access any
>   of your saved options from within your code you can use your global
>   variable: $stackover

First thing I did is search this error on Google. If found 'dev_mode' problem then I checked it. They were saying disable developer mode but it is already disabled in theme_options.php

> 'dev_mode'             => false,

So what should I do to fix that error?

Answer (score 0):

Set `ajax_save` to false to see the error on saving and debug what's going on.